# Terraform - Use of environment variables in TF files

Tags: terraform, terraform-cloud

I would like to use environment variables in my TF files. How can I mention them in those files?

**I use Terraform cloud and define the variables in the environment variables section.** Which means I don't use my cli to run terraform commands commands (no export TF_VAR & no -var or -var-file parameter).

I didn’t find any answer to this in forums nor in documentation.

**Edit:**
Maybe if I'll elaborate the things I've done it will be much clear.

So I have 2 environment variables named "username" and "password"

Those variables are defined in the environment variables section in Terraform Cloud.

In my main.tf file I create a mongo cluster which should be created with those username and password variables.
In the main variables.tf file I defined those variables as:

```
variable "username" {
  type = string
}

variable "password" {
  type = string
}
```

My main.tf file looks like:

```
module "eu-west-1-mongo-cluster" {
...
...
  username = var.username
  password = var.password
}
```

In the mongo submodule I defined them in variables.tf file as type string and in the mongo.tf file in the submodule I ref them as var.username and var.password

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is supported by Terraform Cloud.  You are setting `Environment Variables` in the UI but you need to set `Terraform Variables` (see screenshot).
For Terraform Cloud backend you need to dynamically create `*.auto.tfvars`, none of the usual `-var="myvar=123"` or `TF_VAR_myvar=123` or `terraform.tfvars` are currently supported from the remote backend.  The error message below is produced from the CLI when running terraform 1.0.1 with a `-var` value:

```
│ Error: Run variables are currently not supported
│ 
│ The "remote" backend does not support setting run variables at this time. Currently the
│ only to way to pass variables to the remote backend is by creating a '*.auto.tfvars'
│ variables file. This file will automatically be loaded by the "remote" backend when the
│ workspace is configured to use Terraform v0.10.0 or later.
│ 
│ Additionally you can also set variables on the workspace in the web UI:
│ https://app.terraform.io/app/<org>/<workspace>/variables
```

My use case is in a CI/CD pipeline with the CLI using a remote Terraform Cloud backend, so created the `*.auto.tfvars` with for example:

```sh
# Environment variables set by pipeline
TF_VAR_cloudfront_origin_path="/mypath"

# Dynamically create *.auto.tfvars from environment variables
cat >dev.auto.tfvars <<EOL
cloudfront_origin_path="$TF_VAR_cloudfront_origin_path"
EOL

# Plan the run
terraform plan
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/workspaces/variables.html#environment-variables, terraform will export all the provided variables.

So if you have defined an environment variable `TF_VAR_name` then you should be able to use as `var.name` in the terraform code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply !
I've tried it several times and the error still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this in my devops pipeline, by copying the terraform.tfvars file from my sub directory to the working directory as file.auto.tfvars

For example:

```
cp $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_demo/env/dev/variables.tfvars  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/demo/variables.auto.tfvars
```